# Error al al ejecutar un docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Estoy intentando ejecutar un docker-compose up me el error.
He actualizado Python, he desinstalado Docker y borrado los ficheros.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 125, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 53, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 145, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 116, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 97, in docker_client
    kwargs = kwargs_from_env(environment=environment, ssl_version=tls_version)
TypeError: kwargs_from_env() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_version'
```

mi Docker docker-compose

```
version: "3.4"
services:
    cam_frontal_Ender3S1Pro:
       image: registry.gitlab.com/luckyturtledev/docker-mjpg-streamer:latest
       ports:
            - '8081:8080'
       command: -i "input_uvc.so -n -d /dev/video1 -r 1920x1080" -o "output_http.so -w  /usr/share/mjpg-st>
       devices:
            - /dev/trust_webcam2:/dev/video1
       restart: unless-stopped
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar seria de ayuda.

Comment: de donde sale  ssl_version=tls_version.. porque se esta quejando de eso...

Comment: Eso no lo se, no me pasaba antes, ese el problema

Comment: El command no está cerrado correctamente. Parece que le falta unas comillas dobles en output.